# Mysql dynamic table generation from normalized data

Tags: php, mysql, database

My goal is to store a form.

**Form structure:**

Section1

section1 table

Section2

section2 table

....

Section S

sectionS table

The tables look like these except i need sum (totals) for both rows and columns. Tables are dynamic in size M by N

[image]

I need to generate 2D table values (with slight variations) on many pages so I want it to be done by the mysql sever instead of with PHP. I’m not sure if I should use views, prepared queries/pivot table, or PHP for this.

I believe this is the correct database schema for storing the form (corrections / suggestions wanted).

[image: Schema]

I like this idea [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832331), but It's too far over my head. This is what i have finished before stopping to make sure there is not a better solution.

```
set @sql = 'COSID ';    
set @sql = concat('select CommitSources.StandardSource, ', @sql, "from CommitSources where CommitSources.CSID = '20' group by CommitSources.COSID;");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;    
EXECUTE stmt;
```

**Question:**

I would like a solution that allows me to send a form PK and section PK and return rows like this so that I can easily manipulate/output them. (*Note this output is missing a row with column totals)

[image: Output format]

1. What is the best way to do this? (PHP, mysql view, mysql prepared, other)
2. Is my database schema correct and normalized correctly for storing this data?